# Shell variable unexpected empty in if-then statement after calling sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a shell script:

```
TOPDIR=`pwd`
FOLDER=$($TOPDIR | sed 's/\//\_/g')
if [[ condition ]];then
  source ~/[$FOLDER]-build/build-env.sh
fi
```

the `TOPDIR` here is `/home/uname/project`, so the variable `FOLDER` is supposed to be `_home_uname_project` because `sed` is called to replace `/` with `_`.

But it goes wrong when executing, terminal tells that `/home/uname/[]-build/build-env.sh: No such file or directory` which, I guess, means that `FOLDER` is unexpected empty in the if-then statement. Can anybody help me with figuring this out?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus It's a useful online tool! Just added it to my bookmark thanks.

Comment: Try to replace `$($TOPDIR` by `$(echo "$TOPDIR"`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it also works because `echo` writes its arguments, `$TOPDIR` in this case to standard output which will be needed by `sed` command.  @Cyrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the output of just

```
$TOPDIR | sed 's/\//\_/g'
```

you'll realize that it's empty; it's trying to execute a command equal to the contents of `$TOPDIR` and pipe the output of that into sed, but there is no output in the first place.

You could do

```
pwd | sed 's\//_/g'
```

instead (no need to escape `_`), which would work.

Or, instead of using an external tool, you could use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
topdir="$(pwd)"
topdir="${topdir//\//_}"
```

with the same result.

Notice that uppercase variable names are discouraged, as they're more likely to clash with existing, reserved names.

Comment: It works with `pwd` instead of `$TOPDIR`! Thanks, especially for explaining me that `sed` needs a standard output to go with.